# Rails Blog engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Looking for a simple blog engine that will support article management.

I have standalone rails3.2x application and authentication system and I have to add blogging engine for site registered users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com), here you can find appropriate tool for your goals.

Blog engines are [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Blog_Engines)

Answer (score 3):

Just discovered this: https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue. Simple blogging engine with few dependencies, which makes it easy to integrate into existing Rails application.

Comment: Not compatible with rails 5 :(